# Dynamic property name concatenation

Tags: javascript, variables, concatenation

I'm looking for an easy way to assign to a variable depending on the value of another variable.

```
device.slot2_clipList[clipNumber] = singleClipDetails;
```

what I'm trying to do is: replace the "2" with another variable, so that i can run the same operation while just changing the
    var slotNumber, and write to the corresponding variable.

i tried

```
device.slot + device.slotNumber + _clipList[clipNumber]
```

but (obviously?), this doesn't work.

How can this be done? (Maybe I named the Question incorrectly, but that was the closest I could think of.)
Thanks

Comment: Create and use a `device.slots` array instead?

Comment: Although I gave the answer, I do agree with @minitech there is probably a better way for your code to be constructed. Having to do this, while perfectly possible is unusual and could lead to errors down the line.

Comment: Also I changed the title of your question. What you're doing is concatenating to get a property name. Doing that for a variable (which is not attached to an object) is much harder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](//stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/90527)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what bracket notation is for

```
var i = 2;
device['slot' + i + '_clipList'][clipNumber] = singleClipDetails;
```

Comment: Paul S answering questions for a Paul S. Inception!

Answer (score 1):

```
device['slotNumber' + _clipList[clipNumber] ]
```

Explanation:

`foo.bar` in javascript is identical (even in performance) to `foo['bar']`. So any object property name can be built up from strings.